# Powershell 2.0 - Copy file to other location

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

How to write powershell script to copy file to other location, including sub folder as well. Example copy fileA from folderA to folderB, in case there are any subfolder within folderB, fileA will copy to that subfolder as well.

Comment: Have you searched at all for this question?  `Get-Help Copy-Item -Full`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it with two commands pretty easily:

```
# Copy file A to folder B.
Copy-Item -Path $fileA -Destination $folderB

# Get all subdirectories of folder B and copy file A to them. 
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderB -Recurse | 
? { $_.PSIsContainer } |
% { Copy-Item -Path $fileA -Destination $_.FullName }
```

It is not immediately obvious to me if it can be done with one command.  At least not elegantly.

Comment: Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess that parameter was added after 2.0.  I will modify it shortly.